# Chefspec delete file with windowslike path

Tags: windows, rspec, chef-infra, chefspec

Im trying to write test for file deletion:

`test/recipes/default.rb`

```
file 'C:/temp/1.txt' do
  action :delete
end
```

`cat spec/default_spec.rb`

```
require_relative 'spec_helper'

describe 'test::default' do

#before do
#  allow(File).to receive(:exist?).and_call_original
#  allow(File).to receive(:exist?).with('C:/test/1.txt').and_return(true)
#end

  let(:chef_run) do
    ChefSpec::ServerRunner.new(platform: 'windows', version: '2008R2') do |runner|
      runner.automatic_attrs['hostname'] = 'somehost'
    end.converge(described_recipe)
  end

  it 'delete scripts' do
    expect(chef_run).to delete_file("C:/test/1.txt")
  end
end
```

But after invoke rspec command I got:

```
F

Failures:

  1) test::default delete  scripts
     Failure/Error: expect(chef_run).to delete_file("C\:/test/1.txt")
       expected "file[C:/test/1.txt]" with action :delete to be in Chef run. Other file resources:

         file[C:/temp/1.txt]

     # ./spec/default_spec.rb:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.64011 seconds (files took 1.27 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure
```

If I set linuxlike path - everything ok, also as you can see I tries to stub file.
Any ideas what Im doing wrong?

P.S.: I'm running tests on linux, ruby 2.1, chefspec 4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you made mistake, in your recipe you have `C:/temp/1.txt` and in your test you check if file `C:/test/1.txt` is deleted.